# Installing ClamAV on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, clamav

I'd like to install ClamAV on my Ubuntu Servers (LAMP). Is it good to go (as a daemon) out-of-the-box, or does it need some configuration? Do I need to add a line to my crontab to update virus signatures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defaut /etc/clamd.comnf (or equivalent on your distribution) should be fine. On CentOs, the antivirus (clamav), the update (clamav-db alais freshclam), and the deamon (clamd) are different packages.

/etc/freshclam.conf use the default 12 update checks a day.

Then, you need to figure out what you actually want to do with your AV: system-wide scan, e-mail antivirus, etc. You'll have to write scripts, or configure your MTA, to perform the scan and report any finding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, by default, ClamAV is configured to do a system-wide scan w/ 12 updates per day?

Comment: @TrentScott No, by default ClamAV does nothing. You have to tell the system what to do with the AV. Linux AV is not much like Windows AV.

Answer (score 0):

"virus scanner on a server" can mean lots of different and unrelated things.

**Do you want to detect intrusions on your server?**

For this purpose, or run clamav from a cron job regularly to scan your system.
You can also use `chkrootkit` or `rkhunter`.

An anti-virus does not *prevent* intrusions to your server, you have to secure it using many other methods.

**Trying to prevent users from uploading, downloading malicious files?**

You have to plug the anti-virus into some application, possibly by installing plugins/modules or writing new code.

**You have another reason for installing an anti-virus on a *server*?**

Then you should detail your motives so you get more direct responses :)